# How can I check if a array is empty?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem; here is a part of my controller; it shows me the results I want.

```
$angebotDetails = Angebot::where('firma',$id)->get();
```

But if there are empty, it shows me nothing, because there are empty.
Now I want if they are empty, it should show me some text, but I dont get it.
I have a foreach who shows me all my results; I tried `isEmpty` like this:

```
@foreach($angebotDetails as $key => $angebotDetail)
  @if($angebotDetails->isEmpty)
  <h4>Wir haben momentan leider keine Angebote für Dich.</h4>
  @endif
```

or

```
if(empty($angebotDetails)
```

or   `=== 0` or `=== '0'` or `= null`

but it shows me nothing, I dont know why.

If I tried `dd($angebotDetails)` it shows me

```
#items: []
```

and if there are something it shows me

```
#items: array[1]
```

Comment: you was using `$angebotDetails` you should use $angebotDetail as i have edited.

Comment: Pay attention at order of execution: you have to check if collection is empty before loop over it. As pointed in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isempty), you can use `$angebotDetails->isEmpty()` or `$angebotDetails->isNotEmpty()` methods which ever better suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$angebotDetails` is an array, so you can check using `count` or `sizeof`

`@if(count($angebotDetails) === 0)`
//it is an empty array
`@else`
//it is not empty
`@endif`

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden using `count()` to check if an array is empty makes perfect sense. Sure, `empty()` does the trick, but it has a wider area of use. `count()` works only on `Countable` types as it should be while `empty()` will work on all kind of types and even nonexistant variables. Which is bad since it can mask unwanted behaviour. `count()` will generate error right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `forelse` directive

```
@forelse ($angebotDetails as $key => $angebotDetail)
    //
@empty
    <h4>Wir haben momentan leider keine Angebote für Dich.</h4>
@endforelse
```

The code which you use to check if the `$angebotDetails` is empty won't work. Your code will get into the `foreach` loop directive only if the `$angebotDetails` contain some results otherwise it will skip all the code in the `foreach` directive

Answer (score 0):

Check if $angebotDetails is empty before your foreach like this:

```
@if (count($angebotDetails)) // $angebotDetails is NOT empty
    @foreach($angebotDetails as $key => $angebotDetail)
        // do something with $angebotDetail
    @endforeach
@elseif // $angebotDetails IS empty
    <h4>Wir haben momentan leider keine Angebote für Dich.</h4>
@endif
```